# Исходный код страницы в переменную

Tags: php

Как исходный код страницы записать в переменую для ее последующей обработки? (echo $sourse; например)

Comment: можете еще глянуть

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:
Если страницу надо получить с удаленного сервера:

1.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

2.

```
$handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $homepage = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
echo $homepage;
```

3.

```
$file = fopen («http://www.example.com/», «r»);
$homepage = "";
while (!feof ($file)){
$homepage .= fread ($file, 512);
}
fclose ($file);
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: В третьем варианте третья строка: там точно точка должна стоять?

Comment: обязательно, это склейка строк в одну переменную.

Comment: учите сокеты, господа )

в место последнего варианта можно просто использовать $homepage=`file_get_contents();`

Comment: Второй и третий не работают, а первый возвращяет сам html код страницы. Но и этого мне уже достаточно. Вот только как это преобразовать в текст? htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @igolka97: а в чём проблема, вы же и хотите исходный код? html и есть исходный код, честно.

Comment: @VladD да да, а если я хочу в виде текста? Я просто новичек, и на будущее спрашиваю)) но свою задачу я уже решил)

Comment: @igolka97: в общем случае вам придётся писать собственный парсер html/css, интерпретатор js и сетевой движок. Или воспользоваться готовым браузером. Руками из html вытянуть видимый текст достаточно сложно, поверьте.

Comment: Если надо преобразовать в текст для этого существует функция striptags(); но я так понимаю вам надо выбрать текст именно из страницы т.е. из какого-то определенного контейнера к примеру <div id="content"> тогда надо подключить библиотеку скажем "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" и воспользоватся следующим способом: $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
$text = $html->find('div[id=content]', 0)->innertext;
И вы автоматически получите то что просили

Answer (score 0):

Если вас верно понимаю то - [буферизация php](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php&lr=39).